# Raspbian Jessie wired LAN no DHCPOFFERS from pfSense 2.2.6 DHCP server

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, isc-dhcpd, pfsense

Raspberry Pi B+ running Jessie.  Spare Compaq laptop running [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) 2.2.6 with onboard Realtek NIC for the WAN and a [Micro Center Inland USB Ethernet adapter](http://www.microcenter.com/product/444552/UED011_USB_20_to_Fast_Ethernet_Adapter) for the LAN port.

This configuration is for quick setup and testing and eventually I will purpose build a pfSense PC.

I have the onboard Wi-Fi setup and bridged to the LAN, and LAN and Wi-Fi are supposed to go to an OpenVPN server on the Internet.

All of that is working, except the Pi does not want to grab an IP address via DHCP.  My other Windows laptop works just fine.  The Pi will grab an IP address via DHCP from my Netgear WNDR3800 running stock firmware.

I've done some digging.

1. According to the Pi, it thinks it's not getting a response `No DHCPSOFFERS received`.  I don't recall where I saw this and I can't get to again anyways because I uninstalled the default DHCP client and installed DHCPPCD at the [recommendations](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=624373#p624373) of [someone](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=745371#p745371) on the Raspberry Pi forums.  I also saw that recommendation elsewhere, so I thought it was a good one.
2. According to the pfSense DHCP server, it thinks that it is responding to the pi and giving an offer.

.

```
Feb 28 13:13:34 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
Feb 28 13:13:34 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.1.105 to b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
Feb 28 13:13:47 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
Feb 28 13:13:47 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.1.105 to b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
Feb 28 13:13:50 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
Feb 28 13:13:50 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.1.105 to b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
Feb 28 13:13:53 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
Feb 28 13:13:53 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.1.105 to b8:27:eb:0c:9e:1e (`ACTUAL_HOSTNAME`) via ue0
```

The purge and install of the new DHCP client did not appear to go well.  The Pi GUI says that DHCPD is not starting when I mouse over the network GUI icon.  According to this blog post, [it was already there to start with?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-raspbian-desktop-user-interface-update/)

After swapping the DHCP client, the Pi will still grab an IP address from the Netgear router, but does not grab an IP address from pfSense.

What else can I look at?  What can I modify?  Is my Pi hosed with the new DHCP client?

I'm primarily a Windows user, and only have little experience with Posix OS's.  Though, in constantly falling down the Posix tree and hitting all the branches, I'm quickly losing the ability to say that.

**EDIT**

With the new DHCP client, if the Pi boots connected to pfSense, there is not even an entry in `ifconfig` for the adapter, just the loopback adapter.  If I connect it to the Netgear and it's switch, then there will be an entry for the adapter and it will grab an entry.  Plugging into pfSense will not grab a new address from pfSense, nor will rebooting.

**Edit 2**

Before changing DHCP clients, I deleted the leases found in /var/lib/dhcp.  That had no effect.

The Pi at one time did grab an IP address from pfSense (while I was setting up pfSense and it was going up and down).  I saw it in the lease table of the pfSense UI.  Thinking maybe something was stuck on that end, I deleted it.  That had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that adding in a switch (and switching to a Raspberry Pi 2 with a new Raspbian Jessie image) was the solution.  That leads me to believe that someone's [auto-MDIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX#Auto_MDI-X) was not working.  The USB adapter claims auto MDIX, and the chip (SMSC LAN 9514, [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9514.pdf)) in the Pi spupports it, though I don't know if there needs to be further support for it.

What threw me for a loop was the fact that the Raspberry Pi at one point appeared to grab an address, and pfSense was able to see the Raspberry Pi asking for DHCP.

I figure someone down the road will run into a similar problem.